# ElasticSearch Ec2 - BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9300]

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to elasticsearch on ec2 using node client from my local machine. But i am getting below error.

**org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9300]**

Not sure what other properties i should use. Can anyone please help me with this issue. elasticsearch client version used:2.1.0

**node client:**

```
   Node node = nodeBuilder()
            .settings(ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("http.enabled",true).put("client.transport.sniff",false)
            .put("transport.tcp.port",9300))
            .local(false)
            .node();
    client = node.client();
```

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
cluster:
  name: XX

network:
  host: XX


discovery:
  type: ec2
  ec2:
    groups: XX
    availability_zones: XX

cloud:
  aws:
    access_key: XX
    secret_key: XX
    region: XX
```

Comment: usually this error means that port 9300 is already been used. can you check if that's the case?

Comment: There's no elasticsearch process running on your local machine, so nothing listening on port 9300, hence the error. Also you're missing a cluster name in your configuration. however, since multicast has been removed in 2.0, I'm not certain that the node client will work, you should prefer the transport client instead, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398861/elasticsearch-nodebuilder-vs-tranportclient

Comment: I do have cluster name property in my elasticsearch.yml. With the transport client i get a different error. So i am trying out the node client.

Comment: Any other suggestions please?